# BOS>DOH>MEL>ADL, baggage and customs questions

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, connecting-flights, qatar-airways, doh

I'm an American citizen without much experience traveling internationally. I have a long international flight originating in Boston, USA, going through Doha, Qatar to Melbourne, Australia then to Adelaide Australia. It's all on one ticket through Qatar Airways and Qantas for the domestic flight. Per Qatar's generous baggage allowance, I'm taking two checked bags. Assuming I have all boarding passes, my main question is, **will I need to pick up my bags in DOH and recheck them before boarding to MEL, or will I simply transfer to my next flight and my bags will be loaded on the plane to Melbourne?**

I do know I have to collect my luggage in MEL to cross the Australian border and go through customs there. I've never done an international to international connection before, only LAX>SYD>ADL where I rechecked and went through customs in Sydney in order to fly domestic to Adelaide. **I have 2 hr 10 min between landing in DOH and my flight to MEL.**

Any and all help is appreciated, as a young female solo traveler I'm a bit nervous and confused and really don't want to lose my bags.
Thank you!!

Comment: If you have booked the itinerary as one trip (one PNR) you should not have to pick up your bags in Doha IMHO. What did the airline customer services say when you asked them?

Comment: Most countries handle international transfers without clearing people through immigration nor luggage through customs.  The US is a notable exception.  I doubt Qatar is, but I've never been there myself so I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

> I have 2 hr 10 min between landing in DOH and my flight to MEL.

That's more than enough. Once you arrive in Doha, you will go through passport/boarding pass check right after arrival and then you can just go to your departure gate.

Your bags will be checked through to Melbourne and you don't have to deal with immigration or customs. They only check your passport/boarding pass to verify your identity and confirm that you have an onward ticket, you are not entering Qatar.

> will I need to pick up my bags in DOH and recheck them before boarding to MEL,

No

> or will I simply transfer to my next flight and my bags will be loaded on the plane to Melbourne?

Yes

Comment: Great, that really simplifies it, thank you so much!